# Which HTTP status code should be returned when page is being edited and therefore not available?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

Let's say an URL was public, accessible for all, but right now is being edited and, therefore, is temporary unavailable, but it will be available in the near future.

Which HTTP status code should be returned when page is being edited?

Comment: If you put "http status code temporarily unavailable" into your nearest search engine, you'll find the answer. (Or you could go with `417 I'm a teapot`...)

Answer (score 2):

As told by @JennyD this is as easy as searching just a bit. On Wikipedia you have the list of HTTP error (or status) codes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

503 seem to be the one you are looking for:

> **503 Service Unavailable**
>
> The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.